# Centre element horizontally based on available space

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to centre element horizontally on all the available space left without use of javascript?

I know that if I do `margin: 0 auto;` it will centre it on screen. However, since I have a sidebar I want content to be centred on the **remaining space**, not the screen space.

I know that it is easy to accomplish using javascript, however I wonder if I can make it work with pure css. (https://jsfiddle.net/dxb2rr8k/)

Javascript code would look something like this (https://jsfiddle.net/a5n59bxn/):

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
  centerContent();
});

function centerContent() {
  var sidebarWidth = $('.sidebar').width();
  var contentWidth = $('.content').width();
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  $('.content').css('margin-left', (windowWidth / 2) - sidebarWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html, body, .wrap {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eveniet, iure maiores optio provident quod illum deleniti saepe error corporis molestiae reiciendis omnis, sapiente perspiciatis dolore nesciunt unde, eligendi quisquam reprehenderit. Corporis accusamus beatae, quisquam voluptas deleniti, nam libero dolore, odio maiores blanditiis error sit ad earum iusto quia distinctio.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DaniP Thank you Dani, I've updated my answer. I'm surprised why i didn't think about it :)